# Split core vs. ring ferrite

Tags: arduino, inductive, emi-filtering, ferrite

I have an Arduino clone with L298P motor driver, which drives a linear actuator with a brushed DC motor and a built-in end of stroke mechanical switches and diodes. Motor runs at about 12V/2A DC, on/off control, no PWM. Switches are fairly rudimentary and generate an inductive spike, often large enough to reset the microcontroller. I tried a fast capacitor at terminal of motor driver, but it didn't help. I fixed the problem by placing a sizeable 35mm x 20mm split core ferrite on the motor cable and wound each lead once though about 15mm x 7.5mm ferrite ring. I didn't have time to experiment, which ferrite is sufficient to do the job alone.  In general, would the ring be more effective, perhaps winding the leads through it more than once?

This is my best guess of the internal circuit of the linear actuator:

[image]

At most, one switch (SW1 or SW2) is open at a time.

This is the schematic for L298P part and decoupling capacitors:

[image]

[image]

This shows fair amount of inductive pulse protection already in place.

The rest of schematics showing relevant power regulation and decoupling for ATMega 32U4:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Another developer here. While you say your words, there's really a picture in your mind, which we can never see. A diagram, no matter how crudely drawn, would be immensely helpful. (And that picture will save 1,000 words between us ;-).

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD I added my best guess at linear actuator diagram.

Comment: Wait, so are you trying to find ways to prevent those high-voltage induction spikes? There are better alternatives that you can use instead of using ferrite cores.

Comment: @thisjt What are they? I strongly prefer not to modify motor driver PCB, so I'm limited to placing something on the motor leads, e.g. ferrite, or placing something acrross motor leads at the screw terminal, e.g. capacitor. Also, this is a very cost sensitive project.

Comment: Does your brushed DC motor only go one way, or do you use the L298P (one of the dual full bridge outputs) to make the brushed DC motor go the other way sometimes?

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD Both ways, of course. The circuit shown indicates that. Otherwise, it would be a short travel to the limit switch and no more motion possible.

Comment: _”large enough to reset the microcontroller”_ Classic poor layout or insufficient decoupling causing the EMI issue you mention.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkf9gf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A similar function as your depiction. You notice that at each endstop the motor is disconnected without a free return path for the inductive kickback current. Therefore you must install a varistor or a TVS diode or a RC element in parallel to the motor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuRFMK.png)</sup>

Comment: I don't have access to motor terminals, only to the external leads from the whole circuit.

Comment: BTW, your linear actuator circuit is much better than mine — no power loss on diodes!

Comment: @PaulJurczak If you have the fast switching diodes correctly mounted (it is not clear from  your image) then there should be issues regarding the kickback for the circuit. It is not clear how you do power these boards, 100nF is very small cap for the 5V.

Comment: The schematic is drawn in a weird way, but I'm assuming they got the diodes correctly. I may be wrong. I added the rest of the relevant circuitry.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/126394/146624) by Andy Aka -- it shows the catch diodes for bipolar transistors in the top figure, and MOSFET's
in the bottom diagram (please up-vote his answer). Also, his suggestion to add more capacitance is good.

The following is part of Figure 8 from the Datasheet, and it is for a stepper motor, which is not your application, yet the parts that are noted by red rectangles should provide the excursion-handling that you need to add to the circuit, and I believe that you can add it outside of the board, at least most of it (the diodes).  But for the bypassing of the 0.1uF (100nF) capacitor and the 470uF capacitor, they function best if they are as close to the power inputs of the chip as possible (electrically, and non-inductively).

[image]

You may have to add C3, C4, and/or D1-D8.

Can you look at your board/circuit again?

Comment: Apologies for not posting the relevant schematics. I rectified that.